# AEM CQ 6.1 DAM folder return 0 children in publish

Tags: java, adobe, aem

I have DAM image folder path, and I want to do imageFolder.getChildren(), it returns an empty iterator with no children resource. This only happens in publish instance, and it works in author instance. Any clue? Permission shouldn't be it since I can resolve the path and ask for children, it is not null or anything. Thanks for any help.

```
Resource imageFolder = resourceResolver.resolve(imageFolderUrl);
for (Resource imageResource : imageFolder.getChildren()){
    //empty, doesn't run since getChildren() is 0 sized.
}
```

Comment: open publish instance and check whether the images exist in imageFolder or not. It might happen that you don't have replicate the images from author to publish instance. And if not publish all the image first.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason is simply that some content is "missing" from the Publish server (i.e. it hasn't been activated).  go to `/crx/de/index.jsp` on the publish server and see what content is at the imageFolder path.

Seems like either:

The image folder itself is missing on publish. In this case `resourceResolver.resolve(imageFolderUrl)` would return a "Non Existent" resource rather than null. [See the docs](https://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling5/org/apache/sling/api/resource/ResourceResolver.html#resolve(java.lang.String)). You can check for this:

```
 if (imageFolder.isResourceType(Resource.RESOURCE_TYPE_NON_EXISTING))  {
   //imageFolder doesn't exist
 }
```

Or there are no images under the folder on public.